# How to make the buttons visible in the alertController?

Tags: xcode, uialertcontroller

I having some problem figuring this out. I cant see the cancel button and ok button in my alertcontroller and it is behind the textview. Im using a textview so that there are more space to write on.

[image]

this is the code that i wrote.

```
@IBAction func appltyButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Write your message.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let rect        = CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 240, height: 150.0)
    let textView    = UITextView(frame: rect)

    textView.font               = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)
    textView.textColor          = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.backgroundColor    = UIColor.white
    textView.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth  = 1.0
    textView.text               = "Enter message here"
    textView.delegate           = self as? UITextViewDelegate

    alertController.view.addSubview(textView)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: self.okHandler)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
```

I want to be able to see the buttons. Thanks

Comment: build your own alert lilke `viewController`

Comment: a viewcontroller with in a viewcontroller?

Comment: a `viewController` over a `viewController`?

Comment: can you teach me how?

Comment: Just design a controller with padding around, make background color transparent, set `.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` and present it modally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.addTextField` to add text fields to your alert. Simply adding subviews does not work like you intend and is also explicitly [discouraged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller):

> **Important**
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Alternatively, use one of the many alert libraries out there that allow for more customization, e.g. [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView).